# Javascript Alert won't alert a string?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a bit confused and i'm guessing there's a simple fix so please help.

I have this code (Just a snippet)

```
$new = "1";

<script language="javascript">
    alert(<?php echo $new; ?>);
</script>
```

This works fine. It will alert "1". However, if I change $new to

```
$new = "Hello";
```

It no longer alerts the value? Any ideas?

Comment: you need to use quotes within the alert ~ ie: `alert('<?php echo $new;?>');` or `alert(<?php echo "'".$new."'";?>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quoting your string within the Alert function.

Do this:

```
alert('<?php echo $new;?>');
```

or this, for short

```
alert('<?= $new ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need put to quotes around text in `alert` to alert a String.

```
<script language="javascript">
    alert('<?php echo $new; ?>');
</script>
```

Reason why "1" gets alerted is because, it is considered as an integer and that doesn't require quotes around it.